# My program compute values as string and not as float even when ichange the type

Tags: python, dataframe

i have a problem with my program and i'm confused, i don't know why it won't change the type of the columns, or maybe it is changing the type of the columns and it just still compute the columns as string. When i change the type into float, if i want it to be multiplied by 8, it will give me, for example with 4, 44444444. Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

link = "excelfilett.txt"
file = open(link, "r")
frames = []
is_count_frames = False
for line in file:
  if "[Frames]" in line:
      is_count_frames = True
  if is_count_frames == True:
      frames.append(line)
  if "[EthernetRouting]" in line:
      break
number_of_rows = len(frames) - 3
header = re.split(r'\t', frames[1])
number_of_columns = len(header)

frame_array = np.full((number_of_rows, number_of_columns), 0)
df_frame_array = pd.DataFrame(frame_array)

df_frame_array.columns= header
for row in range(number_of_rows):
   frame_row = re.split(r'\t',frames[row+2])
   for position in range(len(frame_row)):
        df_frame_array.iloc[row, position]=frame_row[position]

df_frame_array['[MinDistance (ms)]'].astype(float)

df_frame_array.loc[:,'[MinDistance (ms)]'] *= 8
print(df_frame_array['[MinDistance (ms)]'])
```

but it gives me 8 times the value like (100100...100100), i also tried with puting them in a list

```
MinDistList = df_frame_array['[MinDistance (ms)]'].tolist()
product = []
for i in MinDistList:
    product.append(i*8)
print(product)
```

but it still won't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df_frame_array['[MinDistance (ms)]'].astype(float)` doesn't change the column in place, but returns a new one.

You had the right idea, so just store it back:

```
df_frame_array['[MinDistance (ms)]'] = df_frame_array['[MinDistance (ms)]'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it raises this error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,25'", i don't understand why it won't change this value

Comment: In that case, it means that you have an entry that is not a float. Maybe "nan" or "not a value"?

Comment: I think i understood this, but on this specific column, there are only values, besides the header called  '[MinDistance (ms)]', but i don't know why it won't change the type of 3,25.

Comment: Oh, that's a "locale" problem. It should have been a `.` instead of a `,`. You can just replace them and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed work, i just need to find how to automaticly change (in the creation of the txt maybe) ',' to '.' and it will be done, thank you again, i was struggling with this problem.

Comment: Great news ;) Happy to help. Accept the answer if it satisfies you ;)